# SQL query when a table has a link to itself

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

Hi say I have a table:

```
Person:
PersonId
Name
ManagerId
```

So the ManagerId is a reference back to another person.

So there might be a persons in the database:

```
1
Bob
null

2
Steve
1

3
Tim
2
```

So Bob is Steve's Manager and Steve is Tim's Manager.

So what I was wanting to do is write a query that gets all the people under Bob's management. Either directly or indirectly. So I would want to get both Steve and Tim. Being in the same line.

If I write:

```
select * from Person
where ManagerId = 1 I would get only Steve.
```

How do I write it so I get everyone directly or indirectly under Bob?

Comment: What database? Different DBs use different methods for this task.

Comment: Is this a tree structure? Like a)Bob is a manager to Steve and George(example).Steve is the manager of Anne and Nick.George is the manager of Stella and Bruce. George has nothing to do with Anne and Nick. Steve has nothing to do with Stella and Bruce. Or is it a simple chain? Bob->Steve->Tim->Nick->Stella->etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to solve this problem.  CTEs can be used for recursion, as Andrei pointed out (see the excellent reference that Andrei included in his post).  Let's say you have a table as follows:

```
create table Person
(
   PersonId int primary key,
   Name varchar(25),
   ManagerId int foreign Key references Person(PersonId)
)
```

and let's insert the following data into the table:

```
insert into Person (PersonId, Name, ManagerId) values 
    (1,'Bob', null),
    (2, 'Steve',1),
    (3, 'Tim', 2)
    (4, 'John', 3),
    (5, 'James', null),
    (6, 'Joe', 5)
```

then we want a query that will return everyone who directly or indirectly reports to Bob, which would be Steve, Tim and John.  We don't want to return James and Bob, since they report to no one, or Joe, since he reports to James.  This can be done with a CTE query as follows:

```
WITH Managers AS 
( 
     --initialize
     SELECT PersonId, Name, ManagerId  
        FROM Person WHERE ManagerId =1
     UNION ALL 
     --recursion 
     SELECT p.PersonId, p.Name, p.ManagerId 
        FROM Person p INNER JOIN Managers m  
        ON p.ManagerId = m.PersonId 
) 
SELECT * FROM Managers
```

This query returns the correct results:

```
PersonId    Name                      ManagerId
----------- ------------------------- -----------
2           Steve                     1
3           Tim                       2
4           John                      3
```

**Edit:** This answer is valid assuming the OP is using SQL Server 2005 or higher.  I do not know if this syntax is valid in MySQL or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use CTE, as @AndreiDrynov pointed out, like this:

```
;WITH Emps(PersonId, Name, PersonLevel, ManagerName)
AS
(
    SELECT PersonId, Name, 0 AS PersonLevel, 
           CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), 'No Manager') AS ManagerName
    FROM Persons
    WHERE ManagerId IS NULL
    Union All
    SELECT p.PersonId, P.Name, e.PersonLevel + 1 , e.Name 
    FROM Persons p 
    INNER JOIN Emps e ON p.ManagerId = e.PersonId 
 ) 
SELECT * 
FROM Emps 
WHERE PersonLevel <= 2
```

This query should give you the following:

```
  PersonId   |   Name  |  Peroson Level   |   Manager
 ------------+---------+------------------+--------------
     1           Bob           0             No Manager
     2          Steve          1                Bob
     3           Tim           2               Steve
```

You can see it in action here:

### [DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71179)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from Person A 
inner join Person B ON B.PersonID = A.ManagerID
where ManagerId = 1
```